# What would happen if my power trips while I'm installing Ubuntu?

Tags: installation

As the title says, what would happen if, while installing Ubuntu 12.04 (or any version), my electricity trips and my PC turns off. Will I need to reboot from the DVD and install from scratch? And would my previous installation attempt be corrupted?

It's not happened to me, but I've often wondered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your installation might become corrupt but you can repair it with a live CD or USB.
For documentation how to repair it, please search askubuntu as I have seen it here.